# UWP, WinJS project, scrollview works for local machine but not on XBOX

Tags: css, uwp, winjs, xbox

I have a scrollable text div in UWP app, when run on local machine, it scrolls fine but when deplyed to xbox, the scrollbar disappears and div becomes unscrollable. I've already set overflow-y: scroll. Any other setup I need to do to make it work with gamepad?

Answer (score 0):

For both XAML and hosted web apps running on Xbox One, mouse mode is turned on by default for the entire app. When under mouse mode, left stick is for free mode, right stick is for scrolling as the following picture shows.
[image: this picture]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/images/designing-for-tv/mouse-mode.png))</sub>

So you can scrolling by right stick or move the pointer cursor to the scroll bar and press `A` button to let the scroll bar work. The left stick should not allow you to scroll  until you disable the mouse mode , for how to disable the mouse mode please reference [How to disable mouse mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode).

```
<script src="directionalnavigation-1.0.0.0.js"></script>
navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = "gamepad";
```

More details please reference [Mouse mode section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/devices/designing-for-tv#mouse-mode) of the Designing for Xbox and TV article.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that before. Somehow my right stick does nothing. I ended up writing a scrollviewer control to scroll the text box. Do I need to add event handler by myself to enable right stick scrolling?